# Move duplicate records to a different table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a table `MAIN` which has duplicates on `ID` field as below:

```
ID      SYSTEM  FLAG  FIRST_NAME   LAST_NAME       TERMDATE
A021    Alpha   Y     JOHN         DOE             null
A021    Beta    N     JOHN         DOE             05-Jun-17
C045    Beta    Y     PETER        PARKER          null
C045    Omega   N     PETER        PARKER          05-Jan-17
D078    Alpha   N     TONY         STARK           07-Dec-17
D078    Gamma   Y     TONY         STARK           null
X039    Gamma   Y     STEVE        ROGERS          null
X039    Gamma   Y     STEVE        ROGERS          null
```

As you can see I have duplicates in ID field. I want to keep the records with null data in MAIN table and move others to a duplicate table. So I want my MAIN table's output to look like:

```
ID      SYSTEM  FLAG  FIRST_NAME   LAST_NAME       TERMDATE
A021    Alpha   Y     JOHN         DOE             null
C045    Beta    Y     PETER        PARKER          null
D078    Gamma   Y     TONY         STARK           null
X039    Gamma   Y     STEVE        ROGERS          null
```

And the duplicates should be moved to a DUPLICATE TABLE which should look like:

```
ID      SYSTEM  FLAG    FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME      TERMDATE
A021    Beta    N     JOHN          DOE            05-Jun-17
C045    Omega   N     PETER         PARKER         05-Jan-17
D078    Alpha   N     TONY          STARK          07-Dec-17
```

**To be noted the records that are exact duplicates were not moved to duplicate table e.x. X039 would be deleted entirely and not moved to duplicate table.**

I can't come to a script that will achieve this result.

Comment: What have you tried, show us your progress so far. What do you mean should happen to X039?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have identified the duplicates I want to move them instead of deleting and X039 would simply be deleted as its truly duplicate.

Comment: And what happened to the second STEVE ROGERS ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff That record was entirely deleted because its an exact duplicate even ID is duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another option:

Table contents:

```
SQL> select * From main order by id;

ID    SYSTEM     F FIRST_NAME TERMDATE
----- ---------- - ---------- ----------
a021  alpha      y john
a021  beta       n john       05.06.2017
c045  beta       y peter
c045  omega      n peter      05.01.2017
d078  alpha      n tony       07.12.2017
d078  gamma      y tony
x039  gamma      y steve
x039  gamma      y steve

8 rows selected.
```

Duplicates: ranked by TERMDATE within the same ID. Insert them into DUPLICATES & remove them from MAIN. You can't just "move" them (take from *here* and put *there*; you'll have to do it in 2 steps):

```
SQL> insert into duplicate
  2  select id, system, flag, first_name, termdate
  3  from  (select id, system, flag, first_name, termdate,
  4           rank() over (partition by id order by termdate nulls first) rn
  5         from main
  6        )
  7  where rn > 1;

3 rows created.

SQL> delete from main
  2  where (       id, system, flag, first_name, termdate) in
  3        (select id, system, flag, first_name, termdate
  4         from duplicate
  5        );

3 rows deleted.
```

Finally, delete remaining duplicates from MAIN:

```
SQL> delete from main m
  2  where exists (select null from main m1
  3                where m1.id = m.id
  4                  and m1.rowid > m.rowid
  5               );

1 row deleted.
```

The result:

```
SQL> select * From main order by id;

ID    SYSTEM     F FIRST_NAME TERMDATE
----- ---------- - ---------- ----------
a021  alpha      y john
c045  beta       y peter
d078  gamma      y tony
x039  gamma      y steve

SQL>
SQL> select * from duplicate order by id;

ID    SYSTEM     F FIRST_NAME TERMDATE
----- ---------- - ---------- ----------
a021  beta       n john       05.06.2017
c045  omega      n peter      05.01.2017
d078  alpha      n tony       07.12.2017

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your basic question is handled by:

```
insert into duplicates (ID, SYSTEM, FLAG, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TERMDATE)
    select ID, SYSTEM, FLAG, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TERMDATE
    from main
    where termdate is not null;

delete from duplicates
    where termdate is not null;

delete from duplicates
    where rowid not in (select min(m2.rowid)
                        from main m2
                        group by ID, SYSTEM, FLAG, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TERMDATE
                       );
```

If anything might be happening on the database, you may want to wrap all this in a transaction.